# How can I confirm if my security review request has been submitted properly in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, drupal, hacked-site

I submitted a security review request in Google Search Console after my website was hacked but I can see no confirmation anywhere that the issue is pending a review.

The only way I can get a message stating that the review request has been submitted is by submitting another request.

How can I confirm that the system is processing my review request properly or that my issue is pending a review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not confirm that your submit was correct other than the message you received when you sent it. That's the normal procedure. Right now, the [process could take weeks](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/request_review?hl=en):

> Reviews for sites hacked with spam may require up to several weeks to process

Just wait till you see one of the two possibles outcomes:

**If your request was approved**:

> If Google finds that your site is clean, warnings from browsers and search results should be removed within 72 hours.

**If your request wasn't approved:**

> If Google determines that you have not fixed the problem, the Security Issues report in Search Console could display more sample infected URLs to assist your next investigation for example. Malware, phishing or hacked with spam site warnings will remain in search results and/or browsers as a caution to protect users